# Unable to change color of nested link

Tags: html, css, text, hyperlink

I want to be able to mark one of my links on each page with a class active and have the text on it turn black as well as being underlined. I'm running the code on chrome, and I've tried via a live server and natively on chrome.

I can't logically figure out why it won't let me change the color this way.

```css
/* Example CSS */

.nav li a {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: brown;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.active a {
  color: black;
}

.nav li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!-- example.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estyles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="example.html">Example</a>       </li>
    <li><a href="example1.html">Example1</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Your `.nav li a` rule is more specific than your `.active a` rule and therefore takes precedence over it. Read about CSS specificity at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Thanks, for providing a pointer to the relevant resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
.active a {
  color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: No, recommending the use of `!important` is virtually never the best solution

Comment: I can't disagree with you but still it's a solution

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's really appreciated -  I wasn't aware that you can declare importance like that :)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, it's the specificity of your selectors that's the problem. Change your `.active a` selector to `li.active a`:

```css
/* Example CSS */

.nav li a {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: brown;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

li.active a {
  color: black;
}

.nav li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="example.html">Example</a> </li>
  <li><a href="example1.html">Example1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's sorted the problem out, I appreciate you taking the time to explain best practices

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using child selector (>) with the attribute selector `.active > a[href]`

```css
.nav li a {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: brown;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.active > a[href] {
  color: black;
}

.nav li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estyles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="example.html">Example</a>       </li>
    <li><a href="example1.html">Example1</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```